# Is Visual studio project properties right click menu customisable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have both PowerCommands and PowerTools and TFS Power tools installed in Visual Studio 2010.

This has made my right-click menu for projects and solutions to be huge, so much so i have to sometimes scroll through it.

Is there any way of removing items from this menu? A lot of the items i do not use (maybe i should :P)

Answer (score 0):

For Power Command and PowerTools, you need to go into their respective options to remove commands.  For example, for Power commands, go into Tools/Options/Power Commands and remove menu entries there.